# Google HeatMap API throws 2 error messages: H/M is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I have been trying to implement a very simple demo of Google HeatMap for hours.
I almost copied everything from the demo page(on the google map api documentation)
Here is the 2 error messages:

1. Uncaught ReferenceError: H is not defined HeatMap.html:6
2. Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined

[image]

and here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,visualization&sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    // Adding 500 Data Points
    var map, pointarray, heatmap;

    var taxiData = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461),
      //...........so many data here, skip...........
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.756335, -122.403719),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.755503, -122.403406),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.754665, -122.403242),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.753837, -122.403172),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.752986, -122.403112),
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
    ];

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

        heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
            data: pointArray
        });

        heatmap.setMap(map);
    }

    function toggleHeatmap() {
        heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
    }

    function changeGradient() {
        var gradient = [
          'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0)',
          'rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 191, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 127, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 63, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 223, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 191, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 159, 1)',
          'rgba(0, 0, 127, 1)',
          'rgba(63, 0, 91, 1)',
          'rgba(127, 0, 63, 1)',
          'rgba(191, 0, 31, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)'
        ]
        heatmap.setOptions({
            gradient: heatmap.get('gradient') ? null : gradient
        });
    }

    function changeRadius() {
        heatmap.setOptions({ radius: heatmap.get('radius') ? null : 20 });
    }

    function changeOpacity() {
        heatmap.setOptions({ opacity: heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2 });
    }

    $(document).load(function () {

    });

    $(document.body).on("onload", initialize);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/11/9/%7Bcommon,map,util,onion,visualization_impl%7D.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/11/9/%7Bstats,controls%7D.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/11/9/%7Bmarker%7D.js">

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how much help this will be, but [here's a working version](http://jsbin.com/otegob/1/edit) that relies on a very different set of library dependencies. The ones in the source code strike me as very odd; they seem to rely on very odd techniques to initialize the map.

If you don't mind me asking, where did you get the code you're relying on? The modified dependency I used came [from here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps), and I don't believe I've seen anything quite like what you've posted from google before... it seems like it's relying on a modified form of eval to create the maps library, which would be highly unusual. On the whole, the example is quite similar to yours in functionality, only the library building seems to be different.

Comment: I believe the code is borrowed from the source code of https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: That's what I used to fix his example, but the code Franva has is a bit different - look at the bottom of their example, there's a couple of extra scripts that differ from that example.

Comment: Hi Bubbles, the code is copied straightly from google. Here is the link: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: Compare the source of that link to what you posted though - while they're trying to accomplish the same thing, they have a few substantial differences. If you just take the source from that link and try to repurpose it, are you having any problems?

Comment: Hi Bubbles, your code works! Thanks a lot! Although I still haven't figured out what caused the errors. I appreciate your detailed explanation, it's really helpful :)

Comment: Glad to help! Maybe you were just the victim of bad luck, I have no idea how you ended up with the slightly distorted code you did. Anyway, hopefully you have smoother sailing from here when it comes to google maps.

Comment: @Bubbles Thank you :) oh one more question, is it possible to highlight a suburb according to a given post code?